# FastMM showing error in release builds when closing application

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I have some customers reporting an error sometimes when closing my applications:

[image]

This is slightly surprising due to:

1. GetMEM call after FastMM is unsinstalled is a bit weird (user reports he is using commandline functionality of my application, so I will try investigate that, but I do not call anything after an application is terminated. But okay, something worth investigating)
2. I am using release mode settings, so howcome FastMM shows an error message? **That is the most important question for me...**

These are the defines I am using for release builds:

```
  {$undef FullDebugMode}
  {$undef EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
  {$undef CheckHeapForCorruption}
  {$undef UseOutputDebugString}
  {$undef RawStackTraces}
  {$undef LogErrorsToFile}
  {$undef LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile}
  {$undef ClearLogFileOnStartup}
  {$undef HideExpectedLeaksRegisteredByPointer}
  {$define ASMVersion}
  {$define AssumeMultiThreaded}
```

The application is multhreaded, but does not share memory manager with dlls or similar

Comment: can be  a lingering thread that is haunting you at application terminataion. Hard to tell without seeing code...

Comment: Is there any way to prevent FastMM from showing the error message?

Comment: I will investigate. But never seen the problem myself in 15+ years. But yes. However, in release builds I think it is better to suppress any errors. In particular if the problem happens when the application is getting terminated anyways (and all memory released back to OS)

Comment: This does suggest that there is a defect in your program somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FastMM source code](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4/blob/master/FastMM4.pas), you can do:

```
{$undef DetectMMOperationsAfterUninstall}
```

To avoid this error message.

**Excerpt from the source code:**

```
{$ifdef DetectMMOperationsAfterUninstall}
{Invalid handlers to catch MM operations after uninstall}
function InvalidFreeMem(APointer: Pointer): {$ifdef fpc}NativeUInt{$else}Integer{$endif}; forward;
function InvalidGetMem(ASize: {$ifdef XE2AndUp}NativeInt{$else}{$ifdef fpc}NativeUInt{$else}Integer{$endif}{$endif}): Pointer; forward;
function InvalidReallocMem({$ifdef fpc}var {$endif}APointer: Pointer; ANewSize: {$ifdef XE2AndUp}NativeInt{$else}{$ifdef fpc}NativeUInt{$else}Integer{$endif}{$endif}): Pointer; forward;
function InvalidAllocMem(ASize: {$ifdef XE2AndUp}NativeInt{$else}{$ifdef fpc}NativeUint{$else}Cardinal{$endif}{$endif}): Pointer; forward;
function InvalidRegisterAndUnRegisterMemoryLeak(APointer: Pointer): Boolean; forward;
{$endif}
```

Comment: How does this got accepted when it doesn't answer OPs question? It's a workaround, not a solution to any culprit.

Comment: Well it answers the OP's most important question, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't: the question was "how come" and your workaround is "avoid it". Nothing was answered, only suppressed. I'd still be interested **why** FastMM detected such a call - OP nowhere asked for simply avoiding a messagebox.

Comment: FastMM in release mode should not show error messages in my opinion so in that regard the question was answered. "I am using release mode settings, so howcome FastMM shows an error message?" (If the application is getting termniated anyway all memory will be freed back to OS....) But I will of course investigate the problem, but meanwhile end consumers have no benefit of such a dialog box.